Language is not changed in AppCompatTextView
I'm having some problems with changing the language. In my application I use the following code to change the language on my configuration screen:
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
Locale hizconf = new Locale(hiz);
Locale.setDefault(hizconf);
config.locale = hizconf;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

Once this code is executed, all the application components change their language, as can be seen in the following image:

The problem is when I exit the application and re-enter, at that moment, there is an element that once again has the language set by the Android device (Basque), as seen in the image:

When starting the application I use the same code exposed at the beginning of the post to establish the previously modified language on the configuration screen.
The element that always changes correctly in the given examples is of type AppCompatButton. On the other hand, the one with the error is an AppCompatTextView.
From what I have been able to observe, it only happens to me in cases where I use elements of the AppCompatTextView type and do not add the text programmatically, since if I add the text programmatically it does work correctly.
What could be the reasons for this problem and what is the solution?
Thanks in advance.
